# How do you embed Google Drive photos (in a slidshow) via HTML5?

Tags: html, google-drive-api, slideshow, photo

I'm looking for a html5 solution to embed on a website, where the code will automatically retrieve all photos located inside a Google Drive folder (I'm assuming it needs to be set to a Public folder via the share options); then have those images rotate like a slideshow.

The goal is that the html code stays the same, but to add a photo to the slideshow, the only thing you need to do is upload a new photo to that photo folder.

Is this possible?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Picasa Web Album API

https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/code

but not for Javascript. You must use PHP to pull the images and send them to the frontend.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use PHP in this particular situation. The target is not actually a website, it's a digital signage program that allows me to insert an HTML5 block into the interface. Would one of these solutions still work with the Picassa Web Album API?

Comment: you could perhaps pull the data from the api via PHP, and pull your own data lateron from the widget via javascript